# Page orientation in PyMuPDF

Tags: python, pdf, python-imaging-library, pymupdf

I am trying to extract text from some Pdfs. For this purpose I am using PyMuPDF library (1.19.2) in Python. I am however having some trouble understanding the orientation of pages and images in the Pdfs. When I look at the PDF in Adobe reader, the page appears in correct orientation. However when I check the page rotation in Python using the following code, I get a rotation of 270.

```
doc = fitz.open(document_name)
doc[0].rotation
```

Now when I extract an embedded image from the page using the following code

```
import PIL
from io import BytesIO
img = doc[0].get_images()
image = PIL.Image.open(BytesIO(doc.extract_image(img[0][0])['image']))
```

I get an image which is rotated consistent with the page rotation I obtained above. The image is shown below

[image]

However, if I extract the pixmap of the page using the following code

```
PIL.Image.open(BytesIO(page.get_pixmap().tobytes()))
```

The page appears in the orientation which also appears in Adobe reader but not the orientation of embedded image or the rotation value returned above.  This image is shown below

[image]

My question is what do the rotation values mean and how can I make sure I am extracting correctly oriented images and pages from the PDF?

Answer (score 1):

The first key to understanding rotations in pymupdf is found in the following code snippet from [documentation](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/page.html?highlight=get_pixmap#Page.derotation_matrix).

```
>>page.set_rotation(90)  # rotate an ISO A4 page

>>page.rect
Rect(0.0, 0.0, 842.0, 595.0)

>>p = fitz.Point(0, 0)  # where did top-left point land?

>>p * page.rotation_matrix
Point(842.0, 0.0)
```

So, the top-left point in unrotated view has moved according to the rotation matrix to bottom-left.

Now, regarding the difference in the outputs of different functions for you,

- the pixmap are by default made with from page rectangle, i.e. with rotation ([ref](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/page.html?highlight=get_pixmap#Page.get_pixmap))
- in the extract_image, the reference is being used to generate the image you are extracting. You can explore the details of this image, i.e. the transformation it has undergone by running this command: `fitz.image_profile(doc.xref_stream_raw(xref))`. In your case, the xref is given by img[0][0]. The attributes you are interested in are orientation and transformation ([ref](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html#image_profile)).

Additionally, reading the appendix on [image transformation matrix](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/app3.html#image-transformation-matrix) might help you further.

Hope this helps understand how the rotation works and, thus, how to extract images with desired rotation (Hint: put checks using the rotation or set rotations before performing operations).